# Consulta mysql para la tabla temporada y jugador

Tags: mysql, sql

como puedo hacer una consulta para que cada temporada me deje regístratar el promedio obtenido por el resto de los jugadores en esa misma temporada, dentro de mi script tengo las siguientes tablas temporada, jugador, estadisticas, equipos y Temporada_Equipo_Jugador dentro de estas tablas tengo lo siguiente

```
CREATE TABLE equipos (
  Nombre varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  Ciudad varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  Conferencia varchar(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  Division varchar(9) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (Nombre)
)engine=innodb;


CREATE TABLE jugador (
  codigo int NOT NULL,
  Nombre varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  Procedencia varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  Altura varchar(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  Peso int DEFAULT NULL,
  Posicion varchar(5) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (codigo)
)engine=innodb;



CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Temporada (
  idTemporada INT(11) NOT NULL,
  Nombre VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
  FechaInicio DATETIME NOT NULL,
  FechaFin DATETIME NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (idTemporada))
ENGINE = InnoDB;


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Temporada_Equipo_Jugador (
  Id INT(11) NOT NULL,
   Nombre_equipo varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  jugador_codigo INT(11) NOT NULL,
  Temporada_idTemporada INT(11) NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (Id),
  FOREIGN KEY (Nombre_equipo) References equipos(Nombre),
 foreign key (jugador_codigo) references jugador(codigo),
 foreign key (Temporada_idTemporada) references Temporada(idTemporada));
```

Comment: No se entiende tu pregunta, trata de dar un mejor contexto por favor

Comment: Cómo ya sabes el código va como texto

Comment: Cuando dices "el promedio obtenido por el resto de los jugadores", supongo que te refieres a los puntos obtenidos por cada jugador, pero, en ninguna tabla parece haber ningún campo de puntos o entendi mal el planteamiento (?). Saludos.